# Jquery: Not Implemented Error Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

The following produces 'Error: Not implemented' on IE 8

```
$('#id .class')[0]
```

However when I run the same command in the IE console, it succeeds?

I am using jQuery 1.8.3; it is included before all other scripts.

Comment: Are you sure it's exactly this ? Don't you have other things, like for example a console.log (which doesn't exist when the developer tools aren't open) ?

Comment: Where does this code show up?  Has the onload event fired?  (Has jQuery finished loading yet?)

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you wrapped this in the document-ready incantation?

   ```
   $(function() {
       // your code
   });
   ```
2. You can use `.get()` instead of `[]`.

   ```
   $('#id .class').get(0)
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   $('#id .class')[0]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

the problem was assignment to a global

```
global = $('#id .class')[0] // fail
```

Assigning to a local fixed the issue

```
var local = $('#id .class')[0] //win
```

./embarassed